# Run C++ script in PHP

Tags: php, c++, json

I have a C++ program that needs to take data from a PHP script, process it, and return the data to my PHP script.

1. How do you pass the values from PHP to C++?
2. How do you run the C++ script? Do you have to compile it first some how?
3. How do you get the values out of the C++ script?

Comment: You most certainly do not have a C++ *script*.

Comment: via the php cli (command line interface)

Comment: @Dagon, accedental upvote. PHP CLI gains you nothing here, as it doesn't matter what context the PHP script is running from.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart i assume he's running his program on the server so how would you do it?

Comment: Why do you assume that? Why couldn't this be part of a regular PHP page script? He can call PHP's [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), or similar function.

Comment: yup the command line, said that

Comment: Sorry guys I'm still new to programming, so I'm not sure what the correct terminology is Jonathon Reinhart.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**1 .** How do you pass the values from PHP to C++?

***Ans:*** In php file, you could use [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function to execute your C++ binary file.
Example:

```
exec("/path/to/your/binary $var1 $var2", $output);
```

**2 .** How do you run the C++ script? Do you have to compile it first some how?

***Ans:*** Of course, you can't execute the C++ script directly, C++ is compiled language, you could just execute the binary file.

**3 .** How do you get the values out of the C++ script?

***Ans:*** See 1, you will get the output form C++ by `$output`.

Comment: Since this question is likely being viewed by people new to calling the command line from inside PHP I think a word of caution about command injection is warranted.  When using this method as part of a website you have to be careful that someone won't insert commands into your variables (i.e. $var1 $var2 in the example) if you're getting input from the user.

Answer (score 2):

1- you can use `exec` to call external application, use command line parameters

2- C++ is not scripting, its a compiled language, you have to compile it first

3- normal std out will be captured by php `exec` function

Comment: if you want to use webserver with c++ you have to check cgi, then php will use a normal web call to call c++ application and get the results using something like `curl`