# How to call an executable file from a PHP script

Tags: php

I want to run a PHP script which calls an executable cpp file on a remote server.

I have tried like below:

1.Created a cpp file

```
// function example
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int addition (int a, int b)
{
    int r;
    r=a+b;
    return r;
}

int main ()
{
    int z;
    z = addition (5,3);
    cout << "The result is " << z;
    return z;
}
```

Generated its .exe file and put it in server's folder(test.exe)

Step2 : 
Created a php scripts which call exe file using 'shell_exec'

```
<?php 
if (function_exists('shell_exec')){
    echo "Enabled";
} else {
    echo "Disabled";
}
$file = 'test.exe';
if (!file_exists($file)) echo 'File does not exists';
$out= shell_exec($file);
//exec($file, $out);
echo 'ouput is:: ' .$out;?>
```

Also, I've put this PHP file on a remote server and tried to call the PHP script in the browser. But it shows error `Warning: shell_exec() [function.shell-exec]: Unable to execute 'test.exe'`.
I want to echo "ouput is:: 8".

Please help to verify.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11789095/run-c-script-in-php

Comment: It is not question about `C++`. Your program can be written in any language.

Comment: is remoteserver a windows server? has your php-user rights to execute the programm-file?

Comment: Most likely your remote server is a Linux machine, which can't understand exe executables. You have to compile your program explicitly for server architecture.

Comment: yes remote server is windows server

Comment: Try `exec($file);`. You should hopefully at least get some more output.

Comment: @EM-Creations  When using exec($file, $output); shows  'Warning: exec() [function.exec]: Unable to fork [test.exe]'

Comment: About the output you get: I suggest you read the documentation of the php functions `shell_exec()`, `exec()` and the like. The documentation clearly explains how to access the process output.

Comment: @DhanyaSanthosh Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20648949/php-warning-exec-unable-to-fork

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
exec("./test.exe", $out);
```

Note that `$out` will hold the output.
remember that`shell_exec` returns all of the output stream as a string, but `exec` returns the last line of the output.

Comment: it shows Warning: exec() [function.exec]: Unable to fork [./test.exe] in D:\Hosting\10676289\html\cpp\test.php on line 11
ouput is:: Array

Comment: Have you googled  the error? I've googled it for you  & this is what i came across:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20648949/php-warning-exec-unable-to-fork

Comment: tried as in above link , echo system("ulimit -a");  shows Unable to fork